# Mailgun forwarding to dynamic address

Tags: email, routes, mailgun

I'm trying to use Mailgun to create email aliases for my users at my subdomain. e.g. if I have a user whose personal email address is bob.smith@gmail.com, I'd like to configure Mailgun with my subdomain such that emails sent to bob.smith@subdomain.mydomain.com will be forwarded to his email address.

I can create a Mailgun route to accomplish this for a specific user, but I'd like to make this work generally for all users.

One thought is to just use the Mailgun Routes API to create a bunch of routes, one for each user (matching on the subdomain email and forwarding to their user account's email address). However that would require me to maintain a very long list of thousands of routes and keep them in sync with my user database.

It seems better to do the following:

1. have a single Mailgun route that forwards to an endpoint on my server (e.g. mydomain.com/mailgun-inbound)
2. on the server, dynamically look up the recipient's personal email in the user database
3. from the server, forward the email to that recipient's personal email

My problem is that I'm not sure the best way to do step #3 without causing deliverability problems. I can use the Mailgun REST API to recreate the email (with just the recipient changed), but I'm wondering if that's a problem since I'd be essentially spoofing the sender. Is that a valid concern? When Mailgun forwards emails, is it doing anything special to prevent this issue? Alternatively, is there a way to use the REST API tell Mailgun to forward a stored inbound email?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this?

Comment: @Devang I ended up using the approach of dynamically generating Mailgun forwarding routes for each alias. I just use the Mailgun Routes API to make sure to create, update, and delete the routes whenever changes happen in the DB.

Comment: @Devang I went with the other approach with a slightly different use case, where we want to allow users to email back and forth at their aliases. For that, #3 above doesn't cause deliverability problems because the server de-aliases the recipient's email to their personal address, and sends the email FROM the sender's alias, which it looks up in the database and is on our subdomain

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Nick. Dynamically generating mailgun forwarding routes makes sense.